# FFmpeg/Avconv unable to copy subtitles; Unsupported codec?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

I've got an mp4 file with these streams (`avconv -i file.mp4` or `ffmpeg -i file.mp4`):

```
Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream #0.2(eng): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1280x568, 4027 kb/s, PAR 1:1 DAR 160:71, 23.98 fps, 2997 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Stream #0.3(eng): Subtitle: c608 / 0x38303663, 0 kb/s
Stream #0.4(und): Subtitle: text / 0x74786574
Stream #0.5: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 667x1000 [PAR 72:72 DAR 667:1000], 90k tbn
```

I am trying to strip out the first audio stream from the file like so:

```
avconv -i file.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:0 -codec copy file-out.mp4

# OR #

ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:0 -codec copy file-out.mp4
```

The problem is, I get this error:

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
```

So, I checked if something's wrong with the mp4 file itself:

```
avprobe file.mp4

# OR #

ffprobe file.mp4
```

And the output says:

```
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3
Unsupported codec with id 94213 for input stream 4
```

I have no idea what that means. (Apparently something's wrong with the subtitles, but I got the video from iTunes.)

1. What's wrong?
2. Can I simply force avconv/ffmpeg to do what I asked of it (i.e. strip the audio stream & copy the rest as it is)? If so, how?
3. Is there a better alternative for remuxing, that's command-line & actively developed?

---

Apparently I missed the other errors/warnings in the console output before the final error message, like @aergistal suggested:

```
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 2 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 3 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 4 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] track 2: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container
```

Comment: Lack of global headers is not relevant to your muxing problem.

Comment: [This question has been crossposted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957009/ffmpeg-avconv-unable-to-copy-subtitles-due-to-unsupported-codec) (this is discouraged).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth stream apparently is a [CEA-608](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIA-608) subtitle stream, which during the days of analog television signal transmission was caption data *embedded within* the video data. Apparently FFmpeg can extract it but can't [mux](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1778) it to a new container.

As for stripping only the audio, [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) may be of help.

Comment: So based on your answer & comment, `ffmpeg` currently doesn't support doing what I asked of it, and if the ticket is patched, it may in the future. No way to force ffmpeg to just do it right?

Comment: There may be a roundabout way of doing it: Mux only the AC3 and H264 streams into a new container. Try to extract the caption to a SRT e.g. ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -c:s copy file-out.srt. If this works, mux the SRT along with the streams from the new container into a final container.

Comment: I just extracted the 2 subtitle streams as separate srt files and the command ran successfully without any issues. But when I opened them in Notepad++ I see this: http://i.imgur.com/j1MKW8n.png -- Any idea why? I've opened srt files before and they are supposed to show normal text.

Comment: Because they are just raw CEA608 data dumped into the output you specified. [CCExtractor](http://ccextractor.sourceforge.net/about-ccextractor.html) should be able to produce valid SRTs from them.